# Override variable or class keeping the same name but changing types

Tags: c#

I have a model that the API backend is expected that period could ethier be a string like "today","yesterday",etc

Or it could be a `List<int>` like "[9292,8383]","[8891,9333]"

```csharp
internal class CallHistoryModel
    {
        public string period { get; set; }
    }
```

Similar to how you can create a method override using the same name with different parameters is it possible to create either a class override or variable override.

Keeping the same name is important because the class is converted to json when it is sent to the server

To provide more context I know that I can do something like

```csharp
public class CallHistoryModel<T>
    {
        public T period { get; set; }

        public CallHistoryModel(T _period)
        {
            period = _period;
        }
    }
```

However period is not a required parameter that will always be sent and my question is wondering if there is a better alternative that the user would not have to specify the type unless it is being used

Comment: Make it generic?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils That would work but would not be the most elegant solution since period is not always required so having to specify the type when initializing would not be optimal was hoping there was a better way

Comment: Could you just make it an `object`? And expect consuming code to perform a cast when they know what type it has?

Comment: Given that this is a DTO ("the class is converted to json when it is sent to the server"), it might be best to explicitly make it a JToken, and then allow that to be converted wherever server-side code knows what it actually is.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Brilliant! Can't believe I didn't think to just specify it as an object